# Kendo UI Entire View Scrolls on Input Field in iOS only

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a problem with my Kendo UI Mobile app that only occurs on iOS when compiled to an .ipa (works fine when ran in appbuilder app). When I scroll on an `input` or `textarea`, the entire view scrolls. This doesn't make my app totally unusable, but it does give it a very unprofessional feel. I have looked everywhere to find a solution to this problem but have found none.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />

<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
```

Try adding these preferences in your config.xml file. Have worked for me in the past. I hope it helps